# "app" module not found when running flask app using waitress

Tags: python, flask, waitress

I would like to run my flask app using waitress and NXING. Here's part of my project structure:

```
 |__webapp     
    ├── templates
    │   └── index.html
    └── __init__.py
    └── app.py
 |main.py
 |__init__.py
 | ...
```

Until now I always ran my flask application like so: `FLASK_APP=app.py flask run` without any trouble. Now I want to start using waitress so I created a main.py file looking something like this:

```
from waitress import serve

sys.path.append('~/[path]/webapp')
from .. import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

When I want to launch my server via the cmd-prompt with `waitress-serve app:app` the following exception appears:

```
There was an exception (ModuleNotFoundError) importing your module

It had these arguments:
1. No module named "app"
```

I can imagine that the problem occurs when importing "app" from an overlying folder but I'm not able to fix the problem.

**EDIT:**
I forgot to cd to the webapp folder in my project directory but when trying to start the web application a new error occurs:

```
There was an exception (ModuleNotFoundError) importing your module

It had these arguments:
1. attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

**EDIT 2.0:**
The full structure can be seen below:

```
 |__webapp     
    ├── templates
    │   └── index.html
    │   └── dashboard.html
    ├── static
    │   └── styles
    │       └── ...
    │   └── webfonts
    │       └── ...
    └── __init__.py
    └── app.py
 |main.py
 |__init__.py
 |tracking.py
 |results.csv
```

There really isn't much more to it than this. Btw, both **init**.py files are empty

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Did you try `waitress-serve main:app`?

Comment: Yes, the same error but `No module named 'main'` occurs

Comment: Could you post the full project structure?

Comment: Yes I edited the question.

PS: Not sure if it interferes with the cmd `waitress-serve main:app` but I just noticed that I have a function called `def main(self)` in my tracking.py program. I'm currently not at the office to test it but just to let you know

Comment: That surely doesn't help, i would try first to do `waitress-serve app:app` from inside the `webapp` folder. If doing like this the app starts then your problem is in the `main.py` file. I think that the import is not how it should, i'll write it in an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modifying the following:

`webapp/__init__.py`:

```
from .app import app
```

main.py:

```
from webapp import app
```

and from the root folder of your project, which i suppose is the same folder that contains the `main.py`file:

```
$ waitress-serve main:app
```